# Is there a way to give a List only with a name to a function without knowing the type of the list?

Tags: c#, list, function

I need a function to get all parameters of an object. 
My objects are stored in different lists. For example I have a list called Students from the type Student and a list called Lecturers from the type Lecturer.

```
    public static void getinfo(string objectname)
    {
        var foundobject = listname.Find(x => x.name == objectname);
        foundobject.info();
    }
```

Now I want to search for an object with a specific name (objectname) and I want to specify the list which will be searched. But I don't know how I could pass the listname to my function.

Comment: You should pass an IEnumerable of a base interface.

Comment: It looks like you need a List<Person> it is a lot easier this way. Or you can use some Linq extensions like .Select() or .Cast().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could make it generic and pass a `Func<T, string>` to get the property:

```
public static void GetInfo<T>(string objectname, List<T> list, Func<T, string> getProperty)
{
    T foundobject = list.Find(x => getProperty(x) == objectname);
    // ...
}
```

and you call it for example in this way:

```
List<Lecturer> lecturers = new List<Lecturer>();
GetInfo("lecturername", lecturers, l => l.Name);
```

> Now it says "'T' does not contain a definition for 'info' and no
>   extension method 'info' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found

The reason for this is that you use this code in your method:

```
foundobject.info();
```

In my generic method there is no constraint yet, so `T` could be any object. But not any object has a method `info`. So you need a constraint which restricts the possible types that can be used. You could let your classes implement a common interface like `IInformable` which has a `Info` method:

```
public interface IInformable
{
    void Info();
}
```

But instead of letting them implement it directly you could let both classes inherit from the same class `Person` since both have a `Name` and every person should also have one:

```
public abstract class Person : IInformable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public void Info()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Name); // for example
    }
}
```

I have made it `abstract` since persons are not very concrete. But your classes are:

```
public class Lecturer : Person
{
}

public class Student: Person
{
}
```

Now you can add properties to your classes which are specific for students and lecturers only.

Above generic method needs a constraint for `IInformable` because you want to call `Info`:

```
public static void GetInfo<T>(string objectname, List<T> list, Func<T, string> getProperty) 
    where T: IInformable
{
    T foundobject = list.Find(x => getProperty(x) == objectname);
    foundobject.Info();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer ;) I tried it but I get an Error "The type or namespace name 'T' could not be found". I tried getinfo(List<T> listname, string objectname) before I asked the question and there was the same error. Should I use a specific "using System... " at the beginning for that?

Comment: Have you used `GetInfo<T>`?

Comment: I forgot that. Now it says "'T' does not contain a definition for 'info' and no extension method 'info' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found"